# Software design patterns for versioning of domain entities/logic

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design, domain-model

I'm looking for specific software design patterns that can help me understand how versioning of the same entity where the domain logic has changed between the versions, can be solved. The following example illustrates a use case for this problem.

Let's say we have the first version of a form that users are required to fill out looking like this:

```
{
   name: string
}
```

Let's call it `UserFormV1`. Then we make some changes to the form entity, and the users are now required to fill in separate fields for their `firstName` and `lastName`, in other words `UserFormV2` looks like this:

```
{
   firstName: string
   lastName: string
}
```

The forms can be edited after they have been submitted, and these two versions of the form should be able to exist together. In other words:

1. Users that started to fill out the form while `UserFormV1` was the latest version should only care about the `name` field when editing the form in the future.
2. Similarly, users who started to fill out the form while `UserFormV2` was the latest version should care about `firstName` and `lastName` instead of `name`.

Are there any software design patterns that allows you to model this as a single `UserForm` entity in a neat way? Or is this a case where `UserFormV1` and `UserFormV2` has to be modeled as two separate entities? Any suggestions, or resources, on this type of problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: These are specific (and a little bit strange) requirements, and they require a specific solution. It boils down to a tradeoff between reusing the same UserForm for both cases or using  two different forms, but this tradeoff needs some real-world context, not some contrived example. And ["shopping for patterns" questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8492/how-bad-are-shopping-for-patterns-type-questions) are not well received by our community.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @DocBrown I see. I guess two separate entities would be the strategy to go for in this case then, and let the code do the work when it comes to duplication of logic. I don't think the requirement of having the two forms live in parallell is a weird one, since you often don't want to force your users over to the latest version of whatever entity they are operating on.

Comment: @martin: it is weird - if I entered a name with V1, according to your description, I will be never ever able to switch to the firstName/lastName variant, even if I want to. However, if there is a migration process from the old to the new variant, it will not be necessary to maintain UserFormV1 any more.

Comment: Another question: when you say UserForm entity, do you have some kind of UI in mind, where the person's name is just one attribute among others (and your question is, if you have to keep those two UI classes as two versions in parallel in your program)? Or are you talking about the pure data structure for the name data, behind some UI which can handle both versions?

Comment: @DocBrown it's behind some UI that can handle both versions.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of keeping two entity versions with corresponding forms alive in parallel, this is usually tackled by changing the backing datastore and trying to split the existing name field to first and last name. Once done, all users need to provide or edit first name and last name fields
There is no design pattern that I am aware of that makes this process easier.

In my experience the following messy solution is used:

- Write a conversion program that does the easy conversions and allows the use of an exception file to handle the hard stuff (e.g "de la rue" is a surname in some languages, as is "nu'fa'loca"). At this stage the program does not update the database.
- Run the program multiple times, and add records to the exception file as you discover problems. You will probably add logic to handle some newly found rules. Make sure your program reports the number of records that it coverted automatically so you can ensure you are making headway
- As part of the software deployment, run the program in production, updating the database.
- Warn the support staff to expect some grumbles from users. This sort of conversion seldom gives 100 percent success.

This may seem a lot of work, but it will pay off on the future. Trying to handle a name field and first name/last name fields will create a huge amount of technical debt.

Comment: The strategy you're referring to is a migration strategy of the existing UserFormV1 as far as I can see. This does not take into account the requirement of having the two forms living in parallell.

Comment: @martin You are quite right. I am advocating that you push back on the requirement to run both forms in parallel. To do so puts you on the slippery slope towards technical debt. Sorry if this does not directly answer your question.

Comment: I see, thank you for the input, I will consider this as I move along with the modeling.

Comment: @DocBrown Yes your edit is fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you want them to co-exist, then the back end would store all three attributes:  name, firstName, lastName.  It would also have to store a version field.  Then you would need logic for each version.

Sample data definition:

```
{ name: string
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
  version: number
}
```

Then a definition for each version:

```
[ 
 { version: 1
   required: name 
 },
 { version: 2
   required: firstName, lastName
 }
]
```

With this information the display or business layer would be able to enforce required logic, etc.

Note, this is somewhat complex and may confuse your users.  Also, I wouldn't really recommend it.  It may be better as others have suggested to have an upgrade path for your data and deprecate the original attribute in favor of the two new ones.  Also, there would be a need in some part of your application (client and server) to inspect the incoming data and version and verify that is meeting versioning expectations.

In this particular example, the name field is really a derived field.  It's probably:  `first + last + suffix`. Or a combination of user entered fields.  So, I would probably derive that field.  It's really a choice on how you want to store it.  Some systems want granularity so as an example: `Mr. James Doe Jr`.

That could be stored in 1 field, or 4 individual ones.  It's up to you to flesh out those requirements.   And that doesn't account people with multiple names beyond first and last, suffix.  So, it depends on what you are trying to accomplish.  There are pros and cons to both approaches.